# Drupal - How to prevent a block of code to be cached?

Tags: php, html, drupal, apc

I'm a PHP/Wordpress programmer, but I need to deal with an small modification on a `Drupal` website. I noticed that `Drupal` caches pages with `APC`. I have a page where inside it I wanna display a text that is taken from an external website and it will be changing all the time.

So, for simplicity, let's suppose that in that part of the page I just wanna display the current time  (with no cache):

```
<?=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>
```

I just wanna make the smallest modification possible and not complex modifications. I would like to only work in that part of the PHP page specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Drupal 7 which by default doesn't cache much. Your explaination of your pretty limited, if you are using APC cache, most likely either your or your hosting provider is doing some specific things for this to work.

Anyways, short version:

- Disable page cache (which will lower performance a LOT) probably will fix the issue and make your site a lot slower for users.
- Display the date with JavaScript, since JavaScript is run by the browser displaying the current time will always be up to date. Can work with any kind of cache like varnish, memcached etc.